# Choppy animation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I have an animation in iOS with the following code:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

    // constraints which are unrelated to drawingResultsController
    self.leadingSpaceToContainerViewConstraint.constant = 0
    self.trailingSpaceToContainerViewConstraint.constant = 0

    // This controller doesn't have any constraints
    drawingResultsController.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}, completion: { finished in

    drawingResultsController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    drawingResultsController.removeFromParentViewController()
    drawingResultsController.didMoveToParentViewController(nil)
})
```

however, the animation does not look very fluid. It's not terrible by any means but you can definitely tell it is way under 30 fps. Does anybody have any idea as to why could this be? I have already verified everything is on the main thread.

Extra details:

The parent controller's view has a subview which is pinned to the edges of it's superview (the main view), those are the constraints seen above. This subview contains the main views of the controller (i.e. it's there to create a parallax effect as the *drawingResultsController* slides in and out of the screen). *drawingResultsController* is a child view controller added as a subview of the main view, and it doesn't have any constraints. It slides in and out of the screen, and this is the code to slide it out.

This way, the view moved by the constraints is a sibling of the view of the *drawingResultsController*. Both are direct subviews of the main view.

EDIT:

Reducing the animation to just this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut,    animations: {

    drawingResultsController.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width, y: 0)

}, completion: nil)
```

improves the frame-rate a little, but it continues to be an issue. It is more noticeable when setting longer animation times. The usage of CPU and memory look completely normal at the time of the animation.

Thank you

Comment: Are you running other apps @ the same time? What sort of platform are you talking about?

Comment: First thing the constraint are on which view? If they are on drawingResultsController then you should not use frame. Also is it the view which is getting removed instantly. Then you actually have to use alpha to dim the view and then remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Added some details to the question. The issue happens in both the simulator and the device itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it solved on its own. It doesn't make much sense since it happened in both the simulator and the device, and no code was changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, turns out it is solved by rebooting the device.

However the issue also seems to be solved by having a CADisplayLink updating a random layer that's part of your window's hierarchy. I noticed that, because we had an animation running somewhere in our app that was triggered by a CADisplayLink and that solved all slow animations elsewhere in the app!

The hack below solves the issue. Add the code to your main window class (assuming you use a custom UIWindow sub class for your main window):

```
//Hack for slow animation problem that occurs after long uptime of the device, updating a view's layer position that's in the view hierarchy using a display link solves the slow animations.

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *dummyView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;

- (void)enableSlowAnimationHack {
    if (self.dummyView == nil) {
        self.dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [self addSubview:self.dummyView];
    }
    if (self.displayLink == nil) {
        self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animateWithLink:)];
        [self.displayLink addToRunLoop: [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
}

- (void)animateWithLink:(CADisplayLink *)sender {
    self.dummyView.layer.position = CGPointMake((arc4random() % 100) / 100.0, (arc4random() % 100) / 100.0);
}
```